# Filestack - I want to convert an image to a specific pixel size before uploading it to Filestack. How can I do that?

Tags: image-uploading, crop

I am working on an application for watermarking a photo. The application has three main steps: 1) upload the main image file, 2) upload the watermark image file, and 3) apply the watermark to the main photo.

I want to convert the watermark to a specific pixel size, before I upload it to Filestack to perform the watermark transformation. How can I change an image file size to specific pixel dimensions before performing the upload with Filestack?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this issue.

The first on would be to use the 'imageDim' function within the Filestack Filepicker.

It would look like this:

```
client.pick({
   imageDim: [400, 400]
})
```

After the upload is complete you can place your watermark over the image.

If you already have the image uploaded and you want to use the existing file handle, you would do it like this:

```
client.storeURL('https://process.filestackapi.com/resize=height:400,width:400/'+ file.handle)
```

You can also add the watermark call in the storeURL function.